# Update fields in object with mongoose in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple collection in mongodb.
I use mongoose.

I have users model with one field type object.
And I want change this object dynamically. But this code doesn't work, I used `findByIdAndUpdate()`, `findById`, `findOne()`, `findOneAndUpdate()`.

```
const UsersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        likes: {}
    },
    { collection: 'users' });

const Users = mongoose.model('Users', UsersSchema);
const id ="5b4c540f14f353a4b9875af4";
const thems = ['foo', 'bar'];

Users.findById(id, (err, res) => {

    thems.map(item => {
        if (res.like[item]) {
            res.like[item] = res.like[item] + 1;
        } else {
            res.like[item] = 1;
        }
    });
    res.save();
});
```

Comment: Could you explain more exactly what you want to do, please?

Comment: what is your id

Comment: Is it your complete mongoose schema?

Comment: yes, it is complete

Comment: @Aaron do you want to store the thems and the **amount** of linkes per theme?

Comment: @Marcus I want change my object, add new fields, and change old fields. But I can't (

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, for solve this problem you need to add more fields in your schema:

I created one example with this data:

```
const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  likes :[
    {
      thema:{
        type: String
      },
      likes_amount:{
        type: Number
      },
      _id:false
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UsersSchema);
```

I added one user:

```
   var newUser = new UserModel({
      likes:[{
        thema:'foo',
        likes_amount:1
       }]
   });
   newUser.save();
```

[image: item_saved]

Here the code that increment the likes per thema:

```
 const thems = ['foo', 'bar'];
  const userId = "5b4d0b1a1ce6ac3153850b6a";

  UserModel.findOne({_id:userId})
    .then((result) => {

      var userThemas = result.likes.map(item => {
        return item.thema;
      });

      for (var i = 0; i < thems.length; i++) {
        //if exists it will increment 1 like
        if (userThemas.includes(thems[i])) {
          UserModel.update({_id: result._id, "likes.thema" : thems[i]}, {$inc: {"likes.$.likes_amount": 1}})
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
            });
        } else {
         //if doesn't exist it will create a thema with 1 like
          UserModel.update({_id: result._id},
            {
              $addToSet: {
                likes: {
                  $each: [{thema: thems[i], likes_amount: 1}]
                }
              }})
            .then((result) => {
              console.log(result);
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
            });
        }
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
    });
```

Database result of this increment:

[image: incremented_field]

I hope that it can help you.